# Deleting within hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

When running the delete method for an object it does not get delelted from the database

Delete query

```
 @NamedQuery(
                        name = "deleteAppointment",
                        query = "delete Appointment t where t.id = : id"
                ),
```

Method for deleting the appointment

```
   public void deleteAppointment2(Integer appId){
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            TypedQuery query = session.getNamedQuery("deleteAppointment");
             query.setParameter("id", appId);
             query.executeUpdate();
        }catch (HibernateException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Yet when I run the method it does not delete the appointment

Answer (score 2):

You are never executing your TypedQuery

Comment: Added query.executeUpdate(); into the method and yet it still does not delete

Comment: @Robbie you never commit your transaction either.

Comment: Probably you want to rollback it explicitly in case of exception as well.